# passing title from resource file to knockout data-bind attribute

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have following html defined in my cshtml file

```
               <span>
                    @Html.Raw(String.Format(Resources.Test,
                   "<a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" style=\"color: #458ccc; \" data-container=\"body\" data-trigger=\"hover\" data-placement=\"auto right\" data-bind=\"bootstrapPopover: { title: 'title1', content: 'something', template: '<div class=&quot;popover&quot; style=&quot;padding:0px;&quot; role=&quot;tooltip&quot;><div class=&quot;arrow&quot;></div><h3 class=&quot;popover-title&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#458ccc; color:#FFF; &quot;></h3><div class=&quot;popover-content&quot;></div></div>' }\">name1<span class=\"fa fa-question-circle-o\" style=\"font-size:1em;\"></span></a>",
                   "<a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" style=\"color: #458ccc; \" data-container=\"body\" data-trigger=\"hover\" data-placement=\"auto right\" data-bind=\"bootstrapPopover: { title: 'title2', content: 'anything', template: '<div class=&quot;popover&quot; style=&quot;padding:0px;&quot; role=&quot;tooltip&quot;><div class=&quot;arrow&quot;></div><h3 class=&quot;popover-title&quot; style=&quot;background-color:#458ccc; color:#FFF; &quot;></h3><div class=&quot;popover-content&quot;></div></div>' }\">name2<span class=\"fa fa-question-circle-o\" style=\"font-size:1em;\"></span></a>"))
                </span>
```

i want to replace hardcode text "title1" and "title2" from resource file but i am really stuck on how to use Resources.Title1 and Resources.Title2. I get so many syntax errors. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are no title1 or title2 references, I'm also not entirely sure why you'd put so much html in the format, wouldn't `<a href="#">@Html.Raw(Resources.title1)</a>` work?
If there's really some formatting required due to a parameter in `Resources.Test`: `<a href="#">@Html.Raw(string.Format(Resources.Test, Resources.title1))</a>`?